# Xcode can't build on windows share after changing mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, windows-vista

After moving to a other mac (fresh installed OSX 10.5.7 with iphone sdk 2.2.1) i now have several problems.

Often copying files to my mac from the windows vista64 share failes with error -41.

When building an .xproject directly on the windows share it fails with hundreds of errors like the following:
"error : Cannot allocate memory"

I later configured Xcode to build locally.. this didn't really help.

This did work on my previous machine why not on the fresh installed?

Do I have to install a inoffical OSX patch?
Do I have to install some windows patch?

Where do you guys store your projects and did problems occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Apple's Mac OS System Error Codes documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1618), -41 is a file system error that means "Memory full (open) or file won't fit (load)". Note that this is distinct from error -34 "Disk full" and appears to be referring to your system memory (RAM + virtual RAM).

Are you running out of memory? Try using Activity Monitor to see what your resources (especially memory usage) look like when you try to open your project.

Update: I did some more digging and found [this Apple Support thread](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=618794) where someone else had the same problem. The solution to their problem was to change a registry setting as suggested by [this article](http://winhlp.com/node/40). Apparently, Windows is sending a "not enough memory" error to your Mac and OS X is simply reporting *that* error as error code -41.

Comment: It seems you were right the disk was full yesterday so i cleaned up but windows decided not do acknowledge this.

After finally rebooting the windows server and removing the users from the .xproject files i can now compile again.